# Jquery modal window is not working for multiple events

Tags: jquery, json, modal-dialog

I want to accomplish waiting window, for that I took jquery modal dialog.

In one scenario, on tab-> need to check the record is exist or not.

In this case the modal working super fine and do the work for several try also.

but if I want to open same modal for different event its not working.

For example.In my page, user have provission to add items dynamically and at the end use needs to submit all these item to DB.

For this submission I need to open that same modal,But its not working.

Here is my code:

Inside the `ready()`, I am calling the dialog:

```
function WaitingWindows() {
    $("#test").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        zIndex: 3999,
        disabled: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        beforeclose: function (event, ui) { return false; },
        dialogClass: "noclose",
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 'center'],
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $('.ui-widg`enter code here`et-content').css('background', 'none');
            $('.ui-widget-content').css('border', 'none');
            $('.ui-widget-header').css('background', 'none');
            $('.ui-widget-header').css('border', 'none');
            $('.ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove();

        }
    });
}
```

**Modal Div:**

```
 <%--loading Image--%>
        <div id="test" style="float:left;width:100px;height:100px;">
        <div style="float:left;width:100px;">
            <img   id="loading" src="Resources/Image/waiting.gif" />

        </div>
        <br />
         <div style="float:left;width:63px;font-size:medium;font-weight: bold;color:#787878 ;">
             Loading...
         </div>

        </div>

 <%--loading Image end--%>
```

**Dialog open and close:**:

```
 $("#test").dialog("open");$("#test").dialog("close");
```

1st method (Working fine):

```
 $("#txt_orderNo").blur(function () {$("#test").dialog("open");}
```

2nnd method (Not working):

```
 $('#btn_us_submit').click(function () {$("#test").dialog("open");}
```

I also used:

```
$("#btn_us_submit").on('click', function (e) {}
```

but not able to open.

Comment: have you checked browser console for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use in `ready()` function

```
$("#txt_orderNo").blur(function () {$("#test").dialog("open");} )};
```

I think It should be work.

Comment: I used ready() function for initializa the dialog and use$("#txt_orderNo").blur(function () {} to open the dialog..its working fine for this case but not working if i want to open same dialog for other function.for example $('#btn_us_submit').click(function () {$("#test").dialog("open");}

Comment: I pointed out Ravish's answer. he is closing extra `}` in his answer though he suggested to write in `document.ready()` but he has to put whole structure here and in @RajaAshutoshNayak  your case can you create [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for the same?

Comment: Jerry is right, sorry for mistake. actual syntax is $("#txt_orderNo").blur(function () {$("#test").dialog("open");}); You can try this also.   <input type="text" value="Text" onclick="javascript:$('#test').dialog('close');" />

Comment: @ Ravish Patel:i need to open the dialog inside the button click event with some additional operation.

Comment: @ Ravish Patel: As per your suggestion i have called ShowPopUp() in side the button click still have same issue.some controls are dynamically generate and some are static. Blurb() for which this modal is working is a static control and after that some dynamic divs and control, then that submit button ,which is also a static control.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you

```
function ShowPopUp()
{
    $("#test").dialog().dialog('open');
    $("#test").dialog({ autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        zIndex: 3999,
        disabled: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        beforeclose: function (event, ui) { return false; },
        dialogClass: "noclose",
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 'center'],
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $('.ui-widg`enter code here`et-content').css('background', 'none');
            $('.ui-widget-content').css('border', 'none');
            $('.ui-widget-header').css('background', 'none');
            $('.ui-widget-header').css('border', 'none');
            $('.ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove();

             }
        });
}
```

Comment: @ Ravish Patel:I don't have any issue while creating the modal,it working absolutly fine for .blurb() method only .if i want to use the same for other event like $('#btn_us_submit').click(function () {$("#test").dialog("open");} it not working

Comment: Why not you can directly call function of WaitingWindows() on button click event like this $("#btn_us_submit").click(function() { WaitingWindows() }); Please Check may be it work and solve your problem.

Comment: @ Ravish Patel: As per your suggestion i have called ShowPopUp() in side the button click still have same issue.some controls are dynamically generate and some are static. Blurb() for which this modal is working is a static control and after that some dynamic divs and control, then that submit button ,which is also a static control.